# Get value between 160-208 bits in uint256 by web3

Tags: solidity, web3js, nodejs, bit-manipulation

I have uint256 representation of hex string `0x0064ababe1000000000700001ca050ee97607a20445e11b012877b0a4e113388`

```
  uint256 some1 = uint48(someAddress >> 208);
  uint256 some2 = uint48(someAddress >> 160);
```

someAddress is uint256

need to get a value between 160 - 208 bits which is uint48

how to do that by web3.js ?
`shrn(160).and(Web3.utils.toBN('0xFFFFFFFFFFFF').toString()` does not help.